# Consolidating starred content from multiple web apps

Tags: favorites

There are a few web apps (Google Reader, Gmail, Twitter, ...) that allow starring items. I normally use the star function as a way to identify elements that require later action (to read/watch later, to answer later, ...).

Is there a way to consolidate starred elements from different web apps in a single view?

Answer (score 3):

What I tend to do is instead of starring the items on those individual services, I put them all in one service. The one I prefer is [Evernote](http://evernote.com). They have a bookmarklet and browser extensions which may speed up the process. Another benefit you get from using Evernote is you can tag it exactly as you want (e.g. to read, to answer, etc.) rather than an ambiguous star. The only problem is being disciplined enough to use a service like this rather than the star, since the star is so easy to click...

Comment: Evernote is a good option. The problem with it, at least on a mobile device, is integrating the service with other apps. I use Twitter and Google Reader on the iPhone, and they make extremely easy to star content for later reading. Using Evernote would require some sort of bookmarklet on Safari, and perhaps something like Instapaper or Read It Later on Twitter. As it is right now, it would require more steps to open or tag content on a single service.

Comment: @Leonardo: There are ways to [import from both Google Reader](http://blog.evernote.com/2009/08/14/send-blog-posts-from-google-reader-to-evernote/) and [Twitter](http://blog.evernote.com/2009/04/14/evernote_twitter/). I'm not sure if it will work on Google Reader's mobile site though.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [Read Later](http://readitlaterlist.com) instead of trying to unify starred content. Everything that has an RSS feed goes into Google Reader, and inside Google Reader I can now save articles for later (See [Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TwoMustHaveToolsForAMoreReadableWeb.aspx)). I can also save links from Twitter on the iphone. The only thing missing is starred content in Gmail but that's not too bad anyways.

Comment: If this was the solution to your question, please accept this answer so that I question can be closed.

Comment: @Michelfrancis; "Closing" a question has a completely different connotation than you're using here. There's no requirement that a question get an accepted answer. Besides, this answer is over 4 years old, about an app that no longer exists, and the user hasn't been on the site for nearly a year.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a quick way to get your starred questions from each of the Stack Overflow sites you could also use the Stack Overflow API.  I threw together a quick app to demonstrate this:

http://jsbin.com/uzafe